# How to create a temp table within single quote

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, temp-tables

I try to create a temptable within single quote it shows error, it cannot identify the table `#newtable`... it only supports `##table` (global temp table) but I don't want a global temp table, I just want what is the reason behind anyone explain it please.

```
 select 
     column1, column2, column3, ##newtable.columnid as ShipProfile,
     row_number() over (order by Id) as ''RowNumber'' 
 into 
     ##TempProduct 
 from 
     Product 
 left join 
     ##newtable on Product.columnId = ##newtable.ColumnId 
 where 
     MerchantId= ' + convert(varchar(20), @MerchantID)
```

Comment: How are you executing this? You say that you are not using global temp tables, but in the code they are defined with ##.

Comment: i am using global temptable, instead of #temptable, my question is why i cannot use the #temptable inside single quote

Answer (score 1):

To quote from the famous [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html):

> Next thing to observe is that the dynamic SQL is not part of the
> stored procedure, but constitutes its own scope. Invoking a block of
> dynamic SQL is akin to call a nameless stored procedure created
> ad-hoc. This has a number of consequences:
>
> ...
>
> - Temp tables created in the dynamic SQL will not be accessible from the
>   calling procedure since they are dropped when the dynamic SQL exits.
>   (Compare to how temp tables created in a stored procedure go away when
>   you exit the procedure.) The block of dynamic SQL can however access
>   temp tables created by the calling procedure.

So you can either define the temp table (`create table #outertemp (col1 INT Primary KEY ...)`) in the stored procedure where you execute the string (*not* in the string itself!) or you can use global temp tables inside your dynamic SQL.

Comment: could you give any example for this scenario

Comment: Updated my answer, HTH. NB: I had to use the dynamic creation of temp tables once and needed global temp tables because they were needed in more than one stored proc. All worked out very well,  just remember to drop the temp tables when you don't need them anymore, i.e. at the end of your stored proc.

Answer (score -1):

You can either define the temp table `create table #outertemp (col1 INT Primary KEY ...))` in the stored procedure where you execute the string (not in the string itself!) or you can use global temp tables inside your dynamic SQL.

Comment: How does your link (Perl for Oracle) correlate with your answer?